# Using $(this) and data attr when setting css in Object format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble setting the background using jQuery/CSS/data attributes. I've not properly re-factored the code and will probably find a better solution but would like to find out why this doesn't work... it's little difficult to explain... see below

```
$('.promoCarousel').find('.image').each(function(){
    $(this).css({
        'background-image': $(this).attr('data-mob-src'), // DOESNT SET BACKGROUND IMAGE 
        'width' : 288,
        'height' : 288
    })
    $(this).addClass("mobview");
});
```

Is it because I am using $(this) with $(this)??

Comment: Are you trying to set the background-image of an image ?

Comment: Please include the html.  What is in the `data-mob-src` attribute?

Comment: Is `data-mob-src` formatted like: `data-mob-src="url(path/to/img.jpg)"`? cause its not going to work without the `url()`...

Answer (score 3):

Set `$(this)` as a local variable and reference that.

You should do this anyway when making multiple calls to `$(this)` as its better for performance reading from the local variable.

Plus, my guess is you haven't included `url()` in the `data-mob-src` property value. I would recommend concatenating this as I have in the example below:

```
$('.promoCarousel').find('.image').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css({
        'background-image': 'url(' + $this.attr('data-mob-src') + ')', 
        'width' : 288,
        'height' : 288
    })
    $this.addClass("mobview");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `HTML5 data-`, use [.data(key)](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2)

replace

```
$(this).attr('data-mob-src')
```

with

```
$(this).data('mob-src')
```

---

**EDIT: added live example**

[jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/X3M5j/)

Comment: While true, this doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Except that your fiddle works equally well with `attr`  http://jsfiddle.net/X3M5j/1/  This isn't the issue.  It is likely the missing `url( )` as @Curt pointed out, though we don't know for sure because the html was not provided.

Comment: there was also problem that you tried to get data from .image not from parent (.promoCarousel), but i dont see your html structure